# Get raw Low Cardinality values in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

Is there a way to retrieve the underlying values of `LowCardinality` types in Clickhouse? I would also need to retrieve a mapping (in a separate query) of the underlying values to the logical values. I've tried using `lowCardinalityIndices` and `lowCardinalityKeys` but it appears that indices -> keys returned by those functions are a many to many mapping.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your question does not make sense.

Column with LowCardinality does not have a single dictionary. Each part has multiple dictionaries for a single LowCardinality column. That's why your observe this lowCardinalityIndices/lowCardinalityKeys behaviour.